# How to fix incorrect %cd% notation uppon elevating script via VBS

Tags: batch-file

I want to run a script

If it is, it adds the location of the script to `%PATH%` environment variable.

If it is not, it elevates, and then runs itself, to do the thing above.

But no matter what I do, I either get an empty window that is elevated, my code running that not elevated, my code running elevated but in `System32` and therefore with wrong `%cd%`.

The code on the right (different form pastebin at the orange marker) is run in the correct dir, it opens a UAC prompt, and an elevated terminal opens (bottom) with wrong path

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5k0W.png "Original problem"

I think the problem is at the orange marker in image 1, I have tried replacing it with `%~dp0%0` and it worked! *But, only* if run from a cmd terminal, not as a "double click" form explorer

Side note, I expected `%~dp0` to return the full path of the file, but it only returned the dir.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZPtR.png "My atempt at fixing it"

[My code on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/nSaWFbHi)

```
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"="
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~dp0%0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin

pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"

echo %cd%
pause
```

I have removed the add to path part in an atempt to isolate the problem, and prevent myself, and others from adding junk to path:)

I expected the original path to be passed down to the elevated window. Via .vbs, but it didn't. And when it did, it couldn't from explorer.exe

Comment: The post needs to be formatted including all the errors and the whole code. It is currently too broad. Please take a look on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `i expected %~dp0 to return the full path of the file` That's exactly, what you asked for: **d**rive and **p**ath. For **f**ull name, use `%~f0`

Comment: why do `%~dp0%0` ? rather do `%~f0`

Comment: Also what do you get when you change `%params%"` to `%params %"`?

Comment: Elevating a program or script does not preserve the working directory for security reasons. Pass the current working directory as a parameter to the re-run script and `cd` to the passed directory in the elevated script instance if you must preserve the working directory.